# How to make a model with text input of any shape and with tokenize and pad_sequence layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a Text Sentiment Analysis model in TensorFlow using the Keras API.
For Text Sentiment Analysis, I would at first have to tokenize and pad the text inputs.

How can I create a Model which can take an input of a text of any length? Which I would then have to tokenize and pad before feeding it into an Embedding layer?

For example

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token="<UNK>")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
padded_sequences = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen, padding='post', truncating='post')
```

Which I can then use inside a Keras model built with the Functional (or any other) API?
I was hoping to save the preprocessing part along with the model file in .h5 format since it would be pretty easy to work with. But if it's not possible what could be the other way around?

Comment: You can definitely save the model in a ,h5 format. What kind of model do you want? What layers do you intend to use? What will be the exact input of the model? WHat shape will it have? These kinds of questions need to be answered before doing any ML problem. You need to do your own research and learn what kind of models work best with what. It seems you are not very experienced with keras, so I would also suggest learning about it.

Comment: I've already answered these questions. I know that the input shape of the model has to be specific. But the inputs are "texts". And texts can be of any length. Which I would have to tokenize and pad before feeding it into the model. So I was asking how could I add a custom layer which would at first tokenize and pad the texts (of any shape), before feeding them into the input layer of the model.